# Importing Triples with Tinkerpop/bluebrints into OrientDB

Tags: jena, tinkerpop, openrdf

Im trying to import RDF-Triples into [OrientDB](http://www.orientdb.org/) with help of [tinkerpop/blueprints](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki).
I found the basic usage [here](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/OrientDB-Implementation).

Im now that far:

```
import info.aduna.iteration.CloseableIteration;

import org.openrdf.model.Statement;
import org.openrdf.model.ValueFactory;
import org.openrdf.sail.Sail;
import org.openrdf.sail.SailConnection;
import org.openrdf.sail.SailException;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.Node;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.Triple;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.oupls.sail.GraphSail;

import de.hof.iisys.relationExtraction.jena.parser.impl.ParserStreamIterator;
import de.hof.iisys.relationExtraction.neo4j.importer.Importer;


public class ImporterJenaTriples extends Importer {
    private OrientGraph graph = null;
    private Sail sail = null;
    private SailConnection sailConnection = null;
    private ValueFactory valueFactory = null;
    private Thread parserThread = null;

    public ImporterJenaTriples(ParserStreamIterator parser, String databasePath) throws SailException {
        this.parser = parser;
        this.databasePath = databasePath;

        this.initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() throws SailException {
        this.graph = new OrientGraph(this.databasePath);
        this.sail = new GraphSail<OrientGraph>(graph);

        sail.initialize();

        this.sailConnection = sail.getConnection();
        this.valueFactory = sail.getValueFactory();
    }

    public void startImport() {
        this.parserThread = new Thread(this.parser);
        this.parserThread.start();

        try {
            Triple next = (Triple) this.parser.getIterator().next();

            Node subject = next.getSubject();
            Node predicate = next.getPredicate();
            Node object = next.getObject();


        } catch (SailException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            CloseableIteration<? extends Statement, SailException> results = this.sailConnection.getStatements(null, null, null, false);

            while(results.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(results.next());
            }
        } catch (SailException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stopImport() throws InterruptedException {
        this.parser.terminate();
        this.parserThread.join();
    }
}
```

What i need to do now is to differ the types of subject, predicate and object
but the problem is i dont know which types they are and how i have to use 
the valuefactory to create the type and to add the Statement to my SailConnection.
Unfortunately i cant find an example how to use it.

Maybe someone has done it before and knows how to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to convert from Jena object types to Sesame ones and use the

The unsupported project https://github.com/afs/JenaSesame may have some code for that.

But mixing Jena and Sesame seems to make things more complicated - have you consider using the Sesame parser and getting Sesame objects that can go into the SailConnection?